# Find a datatype in list by comparing first value in haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a list of data types and I want to find the one that matches the first value, if it exists. If it does not exist, I want to return a default value.

```
data MyType = MyType String Int
findOrMake :: [MyType] -> String -> Int
findOrMake list x = do  i <- -- find index
                        -- if i is a value, return the x[i]
                        -- if i is not a value, return (MyType x 0)
```

I have an intuition that I should use `fmap` and `find`, but I have never used either before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about a simple recursive solution?

```
data MyType = MyType String Int

findOrMake :: [MyType] -> String -> Int
findOrMake [] s = 42
findOrMake ((MyType mstr mint):ms) s = if mstr == s then mint else findOrMake ms s
```

Answer (score 4):

To provide a default when the item is not found, you can use [`fromMaybe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Maybe.html#v%3afromMaybe):

```
fromMaybe :: a -> Maybe a -> a
```

Combined with `find`, it should look something like this:

```
fromMaybe defaultValue $ find predicate list
```